# Nomenclature in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

I am having a little confusion on the naming of functions in complex analysis.
If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the complex plane and its domain is the complex plane then it's called an entire function.

If $g$ is holomorphic everywhere on the complex plane apart from its poles and its domain is the complex plane then it's a meromorphic function.

But...
If $g$'s domain is extended to the Riemann sphere (and it doesn't have a essential singularity at infinity) is it a "meromorphic function with domain of Riemann sphere" or "holomorphic function with domain of Riemann sphere" or a "rational function"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Holomorphic functions are usually defined over an open set of the complex plane or Riemann sphere.

A holomorphic function defined over the whole complex plane is called *entire*. This is a definition.

A *meromorphic* function is one that is holomorphic except for *isolated* singularities, which must be poles. This is a definition.

A meromorphic function defined over the whole Riemann sphere must be a rational function. This is a theorem.

A holomorphic function defined over the whole Riemann sphere must be constant. This is a theorem.

The only entire functions that extend to meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere are polynomials. (Thanks to [Theo Buehler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/theo-buehler) for pointing this out.)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic#Meromorphic_functions_on_Riemann_surfaces.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just got confused by this wikipedia article; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Definition . See it says that by extending the domain to the Riemann sphere the meromorphic function turns into a holomorphic function.

Comment: @Harry: The terms *holomorphic* and *meromorphic* can also be given more general definitions, for functions from one *Riemann surface* to another. And then it turns out that a "holomorphic function from the Riemann surface $S$ to the Riemann sphere" is (except for the constant function with value $\infty$) the same thing as "a meromorphic function from $S$ (minus poles) to the complex plane".